# LEFT JOIN with multiple row result

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables products,colors,assign with this structure:

**products:**

```
product_id | default_color
1          | 1
```

**colors**

```
color_id | color_name
1        | Black
2        | Green
3        | Yellow
```

**assign**

```
product_id | color_id
1          | 1
1          | 2
1          | 3
```

My query returns only first row from "assign" table, I need to have ALL colors assigned for current product.

Here is a query I use:

```
SELECT * FROM products p
LEFT JOIN assign a ON p.product_id = '1' 
LEFT JOIN colors c ON a.color_id = c.color_id
WHERE p.product_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM products p
LEFT JOIN assign a ON a.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN colors c ON c.color_id = a.color_id
WHERE p.product_id = 1
```

The `join` condition should be made on column names, not on values.
For filtering results, use `where`.

See here a working [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7835/1).

For more info on `join`, see the official docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: A little explanation of WHY they should try this is always nice. Explaining what the difference is between what they have and what you have suggested

Comment: It's better to be the first and explain once the answer has been accepted ;-))

Comment: @Jan And who goes back and explains an accepted answer, no they just move on to hunt for more points

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sad but true. My comment was meant to be ironic.

Comment: @Jan I beg your pardon. I missed the Irony. Not like me at all. But now I know you, I will be expecting it next time

Comment: @RiggsFolly No worries, see you next time then :-)

Comment: Easy guys, i was just preparing the update. And no, i don't hunt for points. I simply answer when i have some free time. 2k points in 600 days is not 'hunting'

Comment: sorry my bad, actually i use a.product_id = c.product_id but it still gives me only 1 result from assign table.. maybe i should start my SELECT right from assign table?

Comment: Provided an sqlFiddle. Also, how are you getting the results from php? Are you sure you're getting all of them? Run this query in a mysql console and check the output. It should be what you're going for

Comment: In fiddle and in console i'm getting what i want but not in php .. codes: 

`$query = $db->prepare("
 SELECT * FROM products p
 LEFT JOIN product_colors_assign a ON a.product_id = p.product_id
 LEFT JOIN product_colors c ON c.color_id = a.color_id
 WHERE p.product_id = 1
");


$query->execute();


print_r($query->fetch());
`

and this is what i get:

Comment: `
[product_id] => 1
[product_name] => iphone
[product_price] => 949.00
[product_default_image] => space-gray.jpg
[product_default_color_id] => 2
[row_id] => 1
[color_id] => 2
[this_color_image] => space-gray.jpg
[color_active] => 1
[color_name] => Space Grey
[color_code] => #505050
`

Comment: @FelixAbdullayev, you need to use `while($row=$query->fetch())
{print_r($row);}`. This loops and gets all rows. Using it only once will get you the first restult.

Comment: @Alex Tartan yes, my bad ))) now i feel so sad for that stupid question i asked )) thank you very much for help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `p.product_id = '1'`  use `a.product_id`

```
SELECT * FROM products p
LEFT JOIN assign a ON p.product_id = a.product_id 
LEFT JOIN colors c ON a.color_id = c.color_id
WHERE p.product_id = 1`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement seems to list all three rows from `assign` table.

I executed your query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM products p
LEFT JOIN assign a ON p.product_id = '1'
LEFT JOIN colors c ON a.color_id = c.color_id
WHERE p.product_id = 1
```

And I am getting the three rows of `assign` table.

Here is my SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50f8bd/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. Everything is the same as yours except I'm using `GROUP_CONCAT()` function to concatinate ALL colors for a given product into one field.

```
SELECT
  p.product_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(c.color_name ORDER BY c.color_name ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS colors
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN assign a ON a.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN colors c ON c.color_id = a.color_id
WHERE p.product_id = 1
```

**RESULT:**

```
product_id | colors
-----------|-------------
1          | Black, Green, Yellow
```

**DEMO:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50f8bd/6

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` made the trick .. but what if have more columns in `colors` table? now i can output names separated by the comma, what if i want `color_id` also be present? This is what i have when added `color_id` to `GROUP_CONCAT(c.color_name, a.color_id ORDER BY c.color_name ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS colours`

`[colours] => Rose Gold3, Space Grey2` - here 3 and 2 are color ids